# Wget latest file from a https url

Tags: wget

How can I Wget latest file from a https url. Below command combined all the files present in the URL;

File_20200819_000021_402.csv
File_20200819_060004_003.csv
File_20200819_120004_973.csv

```
wget -N --user=****** --password='******' -r -l1 --no-parent -A.csv https://url/ -O /home/oracle/testsss.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `-O` parameter

```
   -O file
       The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, 
       but all will be concatenated together and written to file.
```